# Regex: Match first occurrence of a word that start with certain characters

Tags: ruby, regex

Let's say I have a paragraph like following:

```
Hello,
Test-12.2.1 we are testing this
Test-13.12.1 we are testing this
Test
```

I just need to grab the first word that starts with `Test-`. So I will be grabbing `Test-12.2.1` on the above case.

Comment: What have you tried so far and what went wrong?

Comment: Good question. I have already tried different way .. Will update that above. Thank you.

Comment: I expect the downvote was a result of your use of the word “paragraph”. Is it a string? The contents of a file? If it’s a string, say it’s a string and surround it with quotes. It’s also helpful to assign a variable to it (`str = “Hello,...”`) so that readers can refer to the variable in answers and comments without having to define it,

Comment: What is the code you are having trouble with? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ? Please, provide a [mcve].

Comment: Can you provide a *precise* specification of what it is that you want to happen, including any and all rules, exceptions from those rules, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases? Can you provide sample inputs and outputs demonstrating what you expect to happen, both in normal cases, and in all the exceptions, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases? Please, also make sure to provide a [mcve].

Comment: "I just need to grab the first word that starts with `Test-`" – You do it by writing a program which does that. If you have a problem with your program, carefully read the documentation of all the methods, classes, modules, and libraries you are using, write tests for your programs, trace the execution with pen and paper, single-step it in a debugger, then sleep on it, start again from the beginning, sleep on it again, and *then and only then* narrow your problem down to a concise, focused, simple, short, reproducible [mcve] and ask a specific, focused, narrow question on [so].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
str = "Hello,
Test-12.2.1 we are testing this
Test-13.12.1 we are testing this
Test"
```

Then you can do either of the following

```
str[/Test-\S+/]       #=> Test-12.2.1
str.slice(/Test-\S+/) #=> Test-12.2.1
```